# Purple ribbon message issue on a signed PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-form, pdf-lib.js

I am using [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) library to fill form fields in a PDF. I, then, flatten the PDF and sign it using my Digital signature. Now when I open a signed PDF in Adobe Reader it shows a Purple ribbon which has written on it "Please fill out the following form" and has a Highlight Fields button (see attached screenshot).
Can anyone please help me understand how to remove this message and "Highlight" button from the Purple ribbon in the PDF.

Additional Details:

- I have tried iTextShare as well to flatten the PDF + some online service.
- I cannot use "No changes allowed" Certification Level while signing PDFs as it gets signed by multiple users

[image]

Comment: I suspect that pdf-lib isn't flattening all of the fields. Also, when applying the Digital Signature be sure to set the permitted actions to "No changes allowed" to prevent the field prompt from showing.

Comment: @joelgeraci I have tried other ways to flatten fields like iTextSharp etc. Also i cannot set permitted action to "No changes allowed" as this same PDF gets signed by multiple users.

Comment: Please share an example PDF illustrating the issue.

Comment: If there are unsigned signature fields, the ribbon will have the field prompt. That's by design. You can't turn it off.

Comment: @joelgeraci Yes.. but there are no unsigned fields. Also, I cannot change permitted to action to "No changes allowed" since this same PDF gets signed by multiple persons. This part however is working fine. Only issue is this "Please fill out the following form" message